# Sitecore 6.5 - Clean Up Databases option nothing happen / shows when I click on it

Tags: configuration, sql-database

I've a Sitecore 6.5 installed and the databases are huge - Core & Master have 14GB each - and I was looking to get them cleaned up.

After sign-in Sitecore 6.5 Desktop, here are the steps

1. Sitecore start menu
2. Control Panel
3. Database
4. Clean Up Databases

And nothing happens, I did check the logs but nothing is there.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I think the cleanup process can help reduce the sizes but not really sure how much you can reduce considering the sizes of those dbs.
That being said, when you execute the cleanup databases command what will happen is that Sitecore will get the list of databases you select on the dialog and add them to a cleaner job that will get executed.
You should see logs on Audit mode(if you don't have it you can always set them on log4net).

Now back to your original problem(db sizes) one thing I would suggest you to do is run a powershell script to get things like unused items, unused media items(this can be a cause for big dbs - hugh media library), etc.
This can pinpoint a few things on your build that can be improved.

One last thing: I remember that the last time I had to deal with Sitecore 6.5 versions I was using Chrome and some of Sitecore's features were not working with newer Chrome versions. Not sure if that's the case for you but if you are using Chrome I'd suggest you to try in the old Internet Explorer to trigger them just in case. That would explain why clicking on the cleanup databases link and nothing showing up on the logs.

Comment: Internet Explorer did the trick! And many thanks for sharing your thoughts around the Clean up feature, really appreciate it but I was looking the root cause of Clean up not working at all! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

When you said nothing in logs, you mean no action or event trigger captured in logs, though in "DEBUG" mode?

You can try [this](http://www.craigtaylor.us/2014/02/sitecore-clean-up-databases-tool-fails.html)

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654826/sitecore-cleanup-agent-and-database-cleanup
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527521/sitecore-database-cleanup-fails/19635431#19635431

Comment: Siva, I've added DEBUG mode and nothing showed up and it end up that Diego found the problem by asking to get IE instead of another browser.